# Programmatically purchase from a website in C# or javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Hey guys, I'm trying to create a website that can help a user purchase items from other websites. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

I know most of the sites I'm using are sending their information using FORM:POST, but I'm having trouble finding the exact POST packet in fiddler (I'm assuming it's encrypted?), and know that a lot of the sites are using login credentials, so that complicates things a bit.

Is there any way I could use webkit or something to handle all the http stuff, and just pass javascript to fill in the forms? Or is there an even simpler way to create proper POST packets and use a WebRequest?

Thank you!

Comment: This is just a bad idea. The second the website changes a setting or design, your software will fail.

Comment: Are you planning on handling user data on your side and posting that to the site? Are you PCI compliant? Are these sites using SSL? If they are I don't see how that approach could possibly work. If not, should you trust them? The only way I would ever consider doing something like this is if the vendor has an exposed API made for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

1) get permission
2) use their published API

If the sites do not have an API and allow you to use their server process, copy their forms to your site and use post. You can post from your server with credentials using for example CURL

Comment: These are smaller websites and don't have the budget to create a public API

Comment: Do you have any good tutorial or examples with CURL? I can only find the documentation, which looks very promising, but not too much about implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Usually shopping cart and credit-card transaction use SSL and you have to login in the site. So I think it's not so simple to bridge with a javascript or a simple webrequest.

There's not a statndard-simple-way way to do this!

Comment: How would you recommend starting then? I'm trying to use fiddler right now to find the POST data, and im looking through the html to pin down all the inputs in the appropriate form. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're heading for a world of hurt.

First, you should check if what you're trying to do is legal. Does the web site allow "proxy orders"? Or are they forbidden by their EULA?

Second, you'll have to handle the user's confidential data (username, password, credit card number), and especially credit card numbers are calling for troubles.

Third, how are you planning to implement payment methods like PayPal? You're going to collect the user's PayPal credentials in order to make payments on their behalf? (See point number two if answer is yes.)

Fourth, since you have to fake HTTP requests, as soon as the web site changes a single field, your tool will break, how are you planning to handle this?

Or you're trying to automate only the first steps of the orders and not the payment?

Comment: 1) Yes, we've checked with the companies and read the EULAs. 2) It will be encrypted (just like the other websites encrypt), and nothing will be stored on our servers. 3) We aren't implementing paypal, only credit cards. 4) There will be error checking and a team that updates things server side when necessary.

Comment: If you're going to make a post, please spare me the legal and business matters. This is a programming forum, not my 3rd year corporate law class.

Comment: If you contacted the companies to check if you can do it, why can't you simply ask them what you have to POST? It would save you from guessing.

Comment: +1 to everything Albireo said. Also add in PCI compliance. You'll have to be compliant if you want to handle credit cards. Check this out: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pa-dss_v2.pdf

Comment: We are not a merchant, so PCI does not apply.